# How to correctly work with a const string pointer in structure?

Tags: c++

Hello I have a structure with a const string pointers:

```
struct something{
    something(const string & a, const string &b)
    {
        first=&a;
        second=&b;
    }
    const string * first;
    const string * second;
    int somethingelse;
};
```

I got there pointers because I dont want to create local copies of strings and my question is how to correctly work with with values of these strings, I need to do operations like compare strings etc. I tried to do it like this:

```
vector<something> myvec;
something tmp1("hello","world");
something tmp2("hello","world");
myvec.push_back(tmp1);
myvec.push_back(tmp2);
cout << *myvec[0].first;
if((*(myvec[0].first)+*(myvec[0].second))==(*(myvec[1].first)+*(myvec[1].second)))
 cout << '1';
```

But its not really working and valgrind has lot of problems with it.
Will be gratefull for any advice.

**EDIT:---------------->**

Ok guys so you were probably right about the fact I really need to make local copies of strings. I actually found out that making local copies wasnt really issue in my program. The problem was the comparsion between strings.
I got there a sorting algorithm with a lot of comparsions like:

```
if(((myvec[0].first)+(myvec[0].second))==((myvec[1].first)+(myvec[1].second)))
```

or

```
if(((myvec[0].first)+(myvec[0].second))<(string1+string2))
```

what was making a lot of temporary substrings and slowing the program really hard. I fixed that issue with linking strings into one string what made comparsions significantly faster.

```
struct something{
    something(const string & a, const string &b)
    {
        firstsecond=a+'|'+b;
    }
    string firstsecond;
    int somethingelse;
};
```

thanks for advices btw.

Comment: Why do you need a `const string*` in the first place? Use `const string&` if you really don't want to make a copy.

Comment: If you don't make a copy of the stings you're being passed, how do you know they will be around/in scope for the duration of your struct's lifetime?

Comment: i have tried to use const string& in struct but i didnt really find out how to initialize string with values given from constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got there pointers because I dont want to create local copies of strings and my question is how to correctly work with with values of these strings.

To be honest working with pointers in that case is going to be a mess. Mainly because pointers are not that easy to work with as people might think. Just look at the code you have right now. It's buggy because, for example, the default constructor of `something` will copy the pointers, effectively sharing the strings across two `something` objects.

I recommend to drop the pointers entirely and forget about this "performance" problem until you actually have proof that your application's bottleneck is in the copying of the strings:

```
struct something {
    something(const string & a, const string &b)
    {
        first = a;
        second = b;
    }
    const string first;
    const string second;
    int somethingelse;
};
```

Comment: I really need to dont make local copies, is there any other way to not make local copies without pointers?

Comment: You've got to make a copy somewhere. Your current code is broken because the string you point to no longer exists as soon as the constructor is finished.

Comment: `I really need to dont make local copies` Wrong